# VBS Downloader/updater not working

Tags: vbscript

Credit to @Hackoo for the code below. I don't really know what's wrong with it, but it doesn't seem to wanna download the file (http://mollernielsen.eu/AutomaticShutdown/test.bat), which doesn't really make sense to me.

```
path = "http://mollernielsen.eu/AutomaticShutdown/test.bat"
pos = InStrRev(path, "/") +1
Const DownloadDest = "http://mollernielsen.eu/AutomaticShutdown/test.bat"
LocalFile = Mid(path, pos)
Const webUser = "admin"
Const webPass = "admin"
Const DownloadType = "binary"
dim strURL

function getit()
 dim xmlhttp

 set xmlhttp=createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
 'xmlhttp.SetOption 2, 13056 'If https -) Ignorer toutes les erreurs SSL
 strURL = DownloadDest

 'Pour l'authentification de base, utilisez la liste ci-dessous, ainsi que les variables + d'utilisateurs? laisser passer
 'xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false, WebUser, WebPass
 xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false

 xmlhttp.Send

 If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then
   Dim objStream
   set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
   objStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
   objStream.Open
   objStream.Write xmlhttp.responseBody
   objStream.Close
   set objStream = Nothing
 End If


 set xmlhttp=Nothing
End function

getit()
```

I have no clue what is wrong with the code, it seems to start, but no file is saved and there are no errors.

Comment: That's not how Stack Overflow works; you need to include the relevant code **in the question itself**, indicating where the code is broken, what doesn't work, and what steps you took to try and remedy it.

Comment: Code blocks on Stack Overflow are simply indented one tab stop (or four spaces).  See [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL
URL = "http://mollernielsen.eu/AutomaticShutdown/test.bat"
Call DownloadingFile(URL)
'*************************************************************************************************
Sub DownloadingFile(URL)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim objFSO,Ws,objXMLHTTP,PathScript,Tab,strHDLocation,objADOStream,File,ProtocoleHTTP
    Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    PathScript = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName) 'Path of this Vbscript
    ProtocoleHTTP = "http://"
    If URL = "" Then WScript.Quit
    If Left(URL,7) <> ProtocoleHTTP Then
        URL = ProtocoleHTTP & URL
    End if
    Tab = split(url,"/")
    File =  Tab(UBound(Tab))
    File = Replace(File,"%20"," ")
    File = Replace(File,"%28","(")
    File = Replace(File,"%29",")")
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    strHDLocation = PathScript & "\" & File
    objXMLHTTP.open "GET",URL,false
    objXMLHTTP.send()
    If Err.number <> 0 or objXMLHTTP.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox err.description & objXMLHTTP.Status,16,err.description & objXMLHTTP.Status
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
            strHDLocation = PathScript & "\" & File
            Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            objADOStream.Open
            objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
            objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
            objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start
            objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation,2
            objADOStream.Close
            Set objADOStream = Nothing
        End If
    End if
    Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
    ws.Popup "The Download of " & Dblquote(File) & " is finished ! ","5","The Download of " & Dblquote(File) & " is finished !" ,64
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thank you. This sorted it a bit out, though my actual problems was the defined characters. The '<>', ',' ect. IN the echoed' VBScript. Still strugling with line 37 not wanting to echo. Thank you though, for even making this possible!

Answer (score 1):

There's no actual `SaveToFile` method called in the script, but there should be.  The stream is being saved to an object in memory, but never written to disk.  Stick this above `objStream.Close`:

```
objStream.SaveToFile "test.bat", 2
```

Comment: Try `WScript.Sleep 50`.  See if that makes a difference.  No clue why it would, but `WSH` is shorthand for `WScript`.  \*shrug\*

Comment: Ah.  It worked on my machine, but [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_looping.asp) says never to use `While...Wend` as I had.  I changed my answer to `Do While...Loop`.  See whether you have better luck with that.

Comment: This was too big to edit in, it seems, but this is basically what I am trying to do:
http://hastebin.com/fipasinodo.dos
^ The first, upper code is what I have right now, trying to fix,
The lower/buttom code is the one I want a Batch to create.

So I want a batch file, creating the code you see down below in the link.

Comment: Eh? :) ^ Don't know what you mean by that,
but I know that the file works in the %temp% folder, but not in any other...?

Comment: `xmlhttp.Open "GET", strURL, false` makes a synchronous HTTP GET request. As soon as `xmlhttp.send` returns `xmlhttp.status` holds the request status (200 on success).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Tested and it appears you're right.  I removed that part of my answer.